# ActiveMQ: transportConnector specific authentication

Tags: authentication, activemq-classic

I want to configure multiple mqtt transportConnectors on an ActiveMQ broker, one for a protected internal network without authentication and one for an external, less protected network with authentication.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to bind an authentication plugin to a transportConnector or vice versa.

The only option I found is message based authentication use messageAuthorizationPolicy, which can be applied to a transportConnector. But that feels a bit to heavy-weighted to me. Is there really no way to configure authentication on transportConnector base?

Thanks and cheers,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't the concept of per transport authentication in the plugins provided by the broker.  You could write you own broker plugins to do what you want.